# On screen keyboard for accents only

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

Has anyone seen a free, compact onscreen keyboard that only has 1 row of accents?

I would like it to be:

- **Free** - actually free, and doesn't constantly ask me for money...
- **Displays french accents only** - or can be made to do so.
- **Doesn't disappear behind other windows**
- **Usable with Windows 10**

I've seen [FrKeys Xp](http://www.frkeys.com/) used before, but I don't need all of those features and aren't willing to pay £15 for a tool to do this.

Comment: I assume it should put the accent onto a character and not only insert the accent itself. Would it be ok if you type those accents instead of choosing it from an on-screen keyboard? That's how it typically works (e.g. in Germany)

Comment: If you don't need it visually, I'd recommend [WinCompose](https://github.com/SamHocevar/wincompose)

Comment: @Thomas WinCompose is a good tool, yet Windows 10 overrides it with every single key, (except **`** which is needed for some of the characters. It works... but doesn't do all that I need it to do.

Comment: @wizzwizz2 Dunno if you still have this issue, but what do you mean Windows 10 overrides it for every single key? I can type ç and whatever just fine with WinCompose, and you can define your own key sequences.